# calculate compound interest and display the interest for each year

Tags: c

```
void power(float P,float R,float n,float A);
void main()
{
    float A,P,R,n;
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter principal amount:");
    scanf("%f",&A);
    printf("Enter rate of interest:");
    scanf("%f",&R);
    printf("Enter number of years:");
    scanf("%f",&n);
    power(A,R,P,n);
    getch();
}
void power(float A,float R,float P,float n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
          A=1+(R*0.01);
          A=A*i;
          A=A*P;
          printf("For year %d, C.I =%f\n",i,A);
    }
}

I put
Principal = 2000
Rate of interest=3
Years=3
```

I am getting the value of compound interest in negative. The error is in A=A*P; The compound interest must be calculated for each year without using the power function

Comment: Please give full code with main()

Comment: I'm not getting negative value with  power(5.2, 2.3, 6.4, 2.5);

Comment: What values do you call this function with to get negative output? For some specific input, please show us the actual *and* the expected output. Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What will be value of P?

Comment: Start with never using floating point if you need exact calculations. Use integers as fixed-point or scaled to the smallest unit you want to use, e.g. cents (or whatever your smallest currency unit is) or - better - a subdivision of cents.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
void power(float P,float R,float n,float A);
void main()
{
    float A,P,R,n;
//    clrscr();
    printf("Enter principal amount:");
    scanf("%f",&A);
    printf("Enter rate of interest:");
    scanf("%f",&R);
    printf("Enter number of years:");
    scanf("%f",&n);
    power(A,R,P,n);
  //  getch();
}
void power(float A,float R,float P,float n)
{
    int i;
        float intr=0;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        intr=0;
          intr=A*(R/100);
         A=A+intr;
         // A=A*P;
          printf("For year %d, C.I =%f\n",i,intr);
    }
 }
```